# How can I check if a text is present on a URL without declaring the exact text?

Tags: javascript

I am getting the error:
`script.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')`

And I don't understand why. Is the `body` const incorrect?
How can I fix this?

```
const checkForText = (url, text) => {
    const page = fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' });
    const body = page.text;


    if (body.includes(text)) {
        console.log(`Passed. "${text}" found on ${url}`);
    } else {
        console.error(`Failed. Did not find "${text}" on ${url}!`);
    }
}

checkForText('https://dsbelmex.biz/nosotros/', 'equilibrio');`
```

I tried a lot of different things, but nothing worked. I'm still learning JavaScript so I'm quite the beginner.

Comment: Is the `fetch` in the code above meant to be the standard [browser-supplied `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? If so, that code isn't correctly using it at all. See the linked documentation for details. If not (maybe some function provided by a web scraping library?), what `fetch` is it?

Comment: fetch returns a `Promise`, not an object, you'd need to resolve the Promise with `fetch(...).then(response => {})`, or use `await fetch(...)` in an async function. Both of these will give you a [response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

Comment: And `text` is a function, not a property. You need `await page.text()`

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on using `fetch()`, they'll show the correct way.

Comment: `fetch` returns a Promise you have to await (or chain with `.then`).  So to explain your error, the promise it returns has no property `text`  therefore `page.text` is undefined, which you assign to `body` which means `body.includes` throws a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkForText = async (url: string, text: string) => {
    const page = await fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' });
    const body = await page.text();


    if (body.includes(text)) {
        console.log(`Passed. "${text}" found on ${url}`);
    } else {
        console.error(`Failed. Did not find "${text}" on ${url}!`);
    }
}

await checkForText('https://dsbelmex.biz/nosotros/', 'equilibrio');
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't read the body from an opaque request.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to try to access external websites directly or interact with the web in real-time to perform actions like searching a webpage for specific content, unless it is in your own server.

However, I am providing you with a JavaScript function that you can use in your own web development project to search for a specific word on a webpage using JavaScript. You'll need to run this code within a browser's developer console or in a JavaScript environment to see the results. Good Luck!

Example screenshot tested on my browser:
[image]

```js
async function checkForText(url, word) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' });
    if (response.ok) {
      const text = await response.text();
      if (text.includes(word)) {
        return `Passed. "${word}" found on ${url}`;
      } else {
        return `Failed. Did not find "${word}" on ${url}!`
      }
    } else {
      return "Failed to fetch the page.";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return "An error occurred: " + error.message;
  }
}

const url = "https://dsbelmex.biz/nosotros/";
const wordToSearch = "equilibrio";

checkForText(url, wordToSearch)
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```